# Xcode : Why same storyboard design display differently on simulator and device?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm new to swift auto layout. I try to create a story board with simple view in it as below:

[image: My StoryBoard]

When I run this on ipad simulator, it display as below:

[image: Simulator's display]

And when I run it on actual ipad (Air 2) it shown as below:

[image]
Is the top part of the display missing due to "1X" icon located on bottom right corner? how do I get rid of it?

Thanks

Comment: 1x is appearing because you are running a iphone app on ipad simulator :) Check the application to universal app :) and 1x will be removed automatically :)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari : Thanks, that helps :) now i got rid of 1X and display are same on both now as expected. If you move this comment to answer, i can pick it a right answer

Comment: @someone-smiley : Glad I could help :) anyway I had posted it as answer as well just before I could see your comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Is the top part of the display missing due to "1X" icon located on bottom right corner?*

Nope :)
1x is appearing because you are running a iphone app on ipad simulator :) Check the application to universal app :) and 1x will be removed automatically and your view should be rendered fine :)

Answer (score 1):

You might have to change the your project settings to "Universal". Go to your Project and click the Target. Then, under General->Deployment Info, change the Devices from "iPhone" to "Universal"